# How to find number of times static function is called Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I am having a function like the following.

```
public String getDecodedToken() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    if (token == null) {
        String token = ClassContainingStatic
                .findString("static");
        this.token = new String(Base64.decodeBase64(token), "UTF-8");
    }
    return token;
}
```

To test the function, I do not want to mock the ClassContainingStatic class because it will render the test useless. Rather I would like to see that if the call happened to ClassContainingStatic.findString("static") without mocking the object. Is there a way to achieve number of function call made to the real object?

Comment: may be you should mock your class with `doCallRealMethod` ?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly possible with a bit of refactoring. If you extract the call to the static class in a separate method:

```
public String getDecodedToken() throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
  if( token == null ){
    token = createToken();
  }
  return token;
}

String createToken() throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
  String token = ClassContainingStatic.findString("static");
  return new String( Base64.decodeBase64(token), "UTF-8" );
}
```

Now you can create a mock or spy, and simply verify whether the method is called.

```
ClassUnderTest spy = Mockito.spy( new ClassUnderTest() );
String token = spy.getDecodedToken();
Mockito.verify( spy ).createToken();
```

I assumed the `"static"` string is fixed. If not, pass it as a parameter to the `createToken` class, and then you can adjust the `verify` accordingly.

I might have made a mistake in the Mockito syntax, but the general idea should be clear. Only drawback is that you need to create a package visible/protected (or even public if you want, but generally that is not the case) method so that the `verify` call can be made.

Comment: That would beat the purpose of testing as in future if someone changes the call to `ClassContainingStatic.findString("static")` to `SomeOtherClassContainingStatic.findString("static")`, the test would still succeed.

Comment: Also because I am very new to unit testing, hence another question. Should we mock the class under test. Usually I have seen people usually declare a private variable(like `private ClassUnderTest classUnderTest`) and then in `setUp()` they would do `classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest`. What would be the potential difference between the two

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam for new questions, well, make a new question please.

Answer (score 1):

The basic thing you need here is called a spy in Mockito language.

While a mock is a completely new object, a spy wraps an existing instance and forwards calls to its methods to the original object by default, while at the same time supports mocking of method calls or verifying of calls.

But you have another challenge: the method you want to verify seems to be a static method. With Mockito you can't mock static methods. You have two basic options:

1. Refactor so that the method is no longer static and you provide the object which hosts the method on as a parameter to the constructor. This parameter then can be a mock or spy.
2. Use PowerMock to mock static methods. I would only accept the usage of PowerMock in legacy projects, where one needs to create tests with as little refactorng as possible. PowerMock is poerful yet clumsy, slow and prone to causing problems down the road, e.g. by creating lots of classes on the fly resulting in PermGen issues.